# See if a message mentions @here

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to see if a message mentions @here on Discord using the JDA library for Java.

I can already see if a message mentions @everyone using `net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message#mentionsEveryone()` but how do I see if the message mentions @here as well?

I've been looking into `Message#getMentions(Message.MentionType...)` but I'm not sure how to use it correctly as it returns the type `IMentionable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check `message.mentionsEveryone() && message.getContentRaw().contains("@here")`. The `mentionsEveryone()` method checks whether it was an everyone mention, `@here` counts as one since it does mention everyone who is online at the time. To see whether it was `@here` or `@everyone` you can simply check the content of the message for the literal `@here` or `@everyone` using `contains("...")` for each type respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this API, but the [JavaDoc for IMentionable](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/IMentionable.html#getAsMention()) shows, that there is a method called `getAsMention`

> ```
> @Nonnull String getAsMention()
>
> Retrieve a Mention for this Entity. For the public Role (@everyone), 
> this will return the literal string "@everyone".
> ```

So it seems all you need to do is iterate over your IMentionable instances and check if one of them is `"@here"`